# Unusual error with antd Mention component

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using Antd Mention component. The usage is very trivial.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
// import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Mention } from 'antd';

class CommentInput extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="comment-input">
                <Mention />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CommentInput;
```

But I am getting an unusual error in the console: Cannot read property 'getBlockMap' of undefined

[image]

It appears that the error is due to package dependencies in my project:

```
"dependencies": {
        "antd": "^3.4.3",
        "axios": "^0.17.1",
        "d3": "^4.13.0",
        "email-validator": "^2.0.3",
        "firebase": "^4.12.0",
        "history": "^4.7.2",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "moment": "^2.21.0",
        "query-string": "^6.1.0",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
        "react-faux-dom": "^4.1.0",
        "react-icons": "^2.2.7",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
        "redux": "^3.7.2",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
    },
```

I have put together a [git repo](https://github.com/vijayst/mentiondemo) which shows the problem exists with my project dependencies.

Any ideas to resolve this?

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me https://codesandbox.io/s/mo26zko51x
Are you passing anything inside the Mention component that you haven't mentioned.

Comment: No, I am not passing anything. It could be related to package dependencies in my app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**:

upgrade `react-hot-loader` to from `3.1.3` to `4.2.0`

1. Install ncu: `npm install -g npm-check-updates`
2. Upgrade `react-hot-loader`: `ncu -u react-hot-loader`
3. Install packages: `npm install`
4. Rerun `npm run start`

**Detailed answer**

If you place a break on this line of the code, you will see that `contentState` is undefined.

[image]

Then, using `Call Stack` of the Chrome's DevTools, you can track where this `contentState` expected to be defined:

[image]

and eventually you navigate yourself to place, where `react-hot-loader` is trying to call `toString()` method of `Mention`:

[image]

Usually, `toString()` just returns string, but in this case it tries to actually construct `Mention`.

Googling the issue does not give much, but we have discovered the fact that problem is located between `react-hot-loader` and `Mention` initialization.

Removing `react-hot-loader` wrapping, shows that `Mention` keeps working.

btw: you seem to have have misleading comment, that you are not passing anything, because in the project you wrap it with `react-hot-laoder`'s `AppContainer`

This gives an idea of checking if current version of `react-hot-loader` is outdated (read as "has bug in it and can be upgraded")

Checking project's `package.json` with `npm-check-update` shows that it can be upgraded from `3.1.3` to `4.2.0`. Which is major version upgrade, and sounds pretty promising

Running `ncu -u react-hot-loader` and then `yarn`/`npm install`, and then re-running `yarn start`/`npm run start` fixes the problem

**Update**

Just out of curiosity, we can check `react-hot-loader` [releases page](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/releases?after=v4.0.0-beta.3), and we see that version `3.1.3` jumped straight to `v4.0.0-beta.1`.

Checking both versions source code, we can see that content of `resolveType` function, has totally changed. Deeper investigations proves, that `toString` is not called from inspected types, but `createProxy` from `react-stand-in` is used instead.

Now we can be sure even more, that version upgrade was the right thing to do.

Comment: That is awesome. Thanks.